# Create array with parents and childs with deep nested object/array javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, object, nested

I want to store in a mysql table the following relations with a (DAD,SON) table that will look something like this:

```
| DAD    || SON    |
| mike.  || june   |
| mike   || michael|
| june   || elias  |
| june   || pepe   |
```

and so on...

I have an unknown depth nested object that will look something like this:

```
const originalObject = {
      Dad: 'mike',
      sons: [
        {
          dad: 'june',
          sons: [
            {
              dad: 'elias',
            },
            {
              dad: 'pepe',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          dad: 'michael',
          sons: [
            {
              dad: 'elias',
            },
            {
              dad: 'janister',
            },
            {
              dad: 'pepe',
              sons: [
                {
                  dad: 'lester',
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
```

How can i make an array that looks like this :

```
const desiredArray = [
    ['mike', 'june'],
    ['mike', 'michael'],
    ['june', 'elias'],
    ['june', 'elias'],
    etc,]
```

I have already converted the object to an array, but im not sure if it helps... The array right now is like:

```
const parsedObjectToArray =[ 'mike',[ [ 'june', [elias, pepe] ], [ 'michael', [elias, janister, pepe] ] ] ];
```

So, based on the originalObject or the parsedObjectToArray, how can i transform one of this to the desiredArray?? I have searched but i struggling hard! Thanks!

Comment: strange family ... just dads ...

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah :D Its just to make it more simple to visualize

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function that dives down the object and adds to an overall `dads` array.

```js
const dads = [];

function addToDads(obj) {
  obj.sons.forEach(son => {
    dads.push([obj.dad, son.dad]);
    if (son.sons) {
      addToDads(son);
    }
  })
}

addToDads(originalObject);

console.log(dads);
```

See it in action below:

```js
const originalObject = {
      dad: 'mike',
      sons: [
        {
          dad: 'june',
          sons: [
            {
              dad: 'elias',
            },
            {
              dad: 'pepe',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          dad: 'michael',
          sons: [
            {
              dad: 'elias',
            },
            {
              dad: 'janister',
            },
            {
              dad: 'pepe',
              sons: [
                {
                  dad: 'lester',
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
    
    
const dads = [];

function addToDads(obj) {
  obj.sons.forEach(son => {
    dads.push([obj.dad, son.dad]);
    if (son.sons) {
      addToDads(son);
    }
  })
}

addToDads(originalObject);

console.log(dads);
```

Comment: Looks like it is exactly this i was looking for! You are awesome! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursion with [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const
    getRelatives= ({ dad, sons = [] }) => sons.flatMap(son => [
        [dad, son.dad],
        ...getRelatives(son)
    ]),
    object = { dad: 'mike', sons: [{ dad: 'june', sons: [{ dad: 'elias' }, { dad: 'pepe' }] }, { dad: 'michael', sons: [{ dad: 'elias' }, { dad: 'janister' }, { dad: 'pepe', sons: [{ dad: 'lester' }] }] }] },
    result = getRelatives(object);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This answer also looks awesome! Thank you! ^^